# Enabling a Display Manager in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, display-manager

I was wondering if anyone knew how to enable/set-up a display manager which prompts for username and password when the screen boots.  Whenever I start Ubuntu, it goes to the desktop and then a small window pops up a few minutes later prompting me for my password.  I would much prefer a separate screen for logging in, as the home screen can be accessed and interacted with before entering a password, leaving a big security hole on my computer.

I run a dual-boot laptop with windows 7 and ubuntu 13.10; not sure if this is relevant, but figured I'd include it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

matthew had to comment the lines

```
autologin-user=<username>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

in `cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to disable automatic login.

**Original**

You must have enabled automatic log-in during installation. You must disable automatic login in the user settings. If [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/auto-login-ubuntu-13-04/) does not help you please advice [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367566/unable-to-disable-automatic-login-on-13-10) or/and provide us more information about which display manager you are using (`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`) as a starting point.

Comment: I went to user accounts and the automatic log-in was set to off, just as is shown in the second link you provided.  My display manager is lightdm

Comment: Can you please copy/paste `cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` ? (remove/change your username if you wish too) You will probably have to comment/"disable" the lines: `autologin-user=<your_username>` and `autologin-user-timeout=0`.

Comment: After turning off my computer after work, rebooting it showed the display manager doing its job perfectly.  Turning off and then turning on the setting in user settings seemed to do the trick.  Thanks, I appreciate the help!